# /etc/apt/sources.list won't accept URLs with https connection

Tags: debian, apt, https

In Debian Wheezy, my `/etc/apt/sources.list` file looks like this:

```
deb https://mirrors.kernel.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
deb-src https://mirrors.kernel.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free

deb https://mirrors.kernel.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src https://mirrors.kernel.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main contrib non-free
```

When I do a `sudo apt-get update` the following error message appears:

```
E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/https could not be found
```

What is the fix for it?

Comment: For future reference, doing `apt-file search /usr/lib/apt/methods/https` would have pointed you to the missing package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My issue was somewhat similar. My `/etc/apt/sources.list` file did not contain any repo reading https. Yet, I could not install the package. The error I got when I ran the command `sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https` was this:

```
Err http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ testing/main apt-transport-https amd64 1.0.9.5  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/a/apt/apt-transport-https_1.0.9.5_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]
```

On close observation of the error, I thought maybe apt was pointing me to an obsolete package. So I manually tracked the package by browsing `http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/a/apt/`. There I found that the version `apt-transport-https_1.0.9.5_amd64.deb` did not exist and hence apt failed to fetch the package.

In order to fix the issue, I downloaded `apt-transport-https_1.0.9.6_amd64.deb` from the link and installed the deb package using `dpkg -i apt-transport-https*`. After that, when I ran `sudo apt-get update`, it worked fine.

If in case the source file is fine but apt fails to fetch a package, manually tracking the package might provide a solution.

Answer (score 7):

You should install the package [`apt-transport-https`](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/apt-transport-https). You might need to temporarily edit that sources.list to read `http` instead of `https:` if you have to download that package.

Comment: This works for the domain name deb.debian.org but not for security.debian.org. Any idea if we can use HTTPS for both domains? It looks like the certificate of https://security.debian.org is not valid. By the way, HTTPS should be the default, I don't understand why they provide it as an option to enable manually...